# Firefox does not show all general options

Tags: firefox

I can see in the picture here 
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/startup-home-page-tabs-download-settings 
that in the bottom of the first general preferences are 6 options, however I only have 3 in mine. 
Do you know what should I do in order to have all possible options on my firefox?

Comment: I got four. Some of the options are only applicable to WIndows OS like the last one. I don't think it's a major issue.

Comment: Read the text regarding the settings on the webpage, ignore the graphic. BTW, the text descriptions of the tab settings are different when checked from Windows vs. Ubuntu (both FF 44.0.2). It are 4 settings in each, but they are not all the same.